# Push to view controller programmatically from container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview

I have a ProfileViewController and in it a container view which is a collection view controller, when the an item is selected in the container view, it will push the whole ProfileViewController to another instance of ProfileViewController. Here is my code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ProfileViewController *profileVC = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
    profileVC.user = self.friends[indexPath.item];
    UIViewController *parentVC = self.parentViewController;
    [parentVC.navigationController pushViewController:profileVC animated:YES];
}
```

However when it pushes the whole view controller just onto a black screen (with tab and navigation bar still showing). Any help how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to initialize the `ProfileViewController` with a nib file, maybe something like:

`ProfileViewController *profileVC = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];`

The string @"ProfileViewController" needs to be replaced by whatever your *.xib* file for this view controller is called. How are you instantianting the view controller  in the first place anyway? Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm using storyboards, how do I instantiate it with a storyboard?

Comment: Well, you don't have to instantiate it from your storyboard, but if you want you can do it with `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` (check the Apple docs for it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Using a navigation controller should work as well though.

Comment: Thanks, one ore question, the container views inside the view controller however aren't updating, they still have the data from the previous ProfileViewController instance.